# Concrete5 - Custom block not editable, or recognized with the editing tool?

Tags: php, concrete5

I'm making a site with conrete5. It's the first one I might add. I have made myself a couple of custom blocks. Named News, Teammates and References.

Now News and Teammates are not editable anymore. I will paste the News -blocks sourcecode.

```html
----------- FORM.php ---------------------
<?php   defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied.")); ?>
<?php
    $al = Loader::helper('concrete/asset_library');
    echo $al->file('optional', 'fID', t('Valitse kuva'), $bf, $args);
?> 

<div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label('otsikko', t('Otsikko'));?>
    <?php  echo $form->text('otsikko', $otsikko);?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label('teksti', t('Teksti'));?>
    <?php  echo $form->text('teksti', $teksti); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label('korkeus', t('Korkeus'));?>
    <?php  echo $form->select('korkeus', array("108px"=>t("Pieni"),"299px"=>t("Iso")), $korkeus); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label('koko', t('Leveys'));?>
    <?php  echo $form->select('koko', array("col-md-3"=>t("Pieni"),"col-md-6"=>t("Iso")), $koko); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label('link', t('Linkki'));?>
    <?php  echo $form->text('link', $link); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $psh  = Loader::helper('form/page_selector');
     echo $psh->selectPage('targetCID', $targetCID); ?>
</div>
----------- view.php ---------------------


<?php 
    defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied.")); 
 
    $c = Page::getCurrentPage();
    if($size=="col-md-3"){
  $class='col-md-3';
        $tag  = $class;
 }else{
  $class="col-md-6"; 
        $tag= $class;
 }
 if ($c->isEditMode()){
  $class="editmode";
  $editingStyle="padding: 15px; background: #ccc; color: #444; border: 1px solid #999;";
 }
 else {  
  $editingStyle = "";
 }
    $random = rand();
    if($korkeus == "299px"){
        $padding = '4px';
    }else {
        $padding = '5px';
    }
    
$p = Page::getByID($targetCID);
      $a = new GlobalArea('Header Navigation');
      $blocks = $a->getAreaBlocksArray($c);
      foreach ($blocks as $block){
         if ($block->getBlockTypeHandle()=="autonav"){
            $block->setCustomTemplate('cdrop.php'); // it's templates/cdrop.php -check the select option values when you set custom template manually at edit mode. I think you will need just "my_template" 
            $bv = new BlockView($block);
            $bv->render('view');
         }
      }
?>
<?php $p = Page::getByID($targetCID); ?>

<a href="index.php">
    <div class="pull-left <?= $koko;?>" style="padding:<?= $padding ?>;<?php echo $editingStyle;?>">
        <div class="col-lg-12 alapalkki box" style="z-index:2;position:relative;">
            <div class="image-big" style="background-color:transparent;text-align:center;position:relative;z-index:1;"> 
            <!-- FiGuRe this shit out......... !-->
                <?php    
            if($fID != 0){
            $file = File::getByID($fID);
            $filePath = $file->getVersion()->getRelativePath();
            }
            ?>
            <?php echo '<img src="' . $filePath . '" style="max-height:' .  $korkeus . ';width:100%;"/>'; ?>
        
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 " style="position:relative;z-index:255;padding:2px 0 0 15px;">
                <div class="htitle">
                    <h4 style="color:white;"><b><?php echo $otsikko; ?></b></h4>
                    <p style="color:white;"><?php echo $teksti; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Why is this not being an editable block? Why doesn't the concrete5 even recognize its existence when it is on the page? It just says at the area that it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p = Page::getByID($targetCID);
      $a = new GlobalArea('Header Navigation');
      $blocks = $a->getAreaBlocksArray($c);
      foreach ($blocks as $block){
         if ($block->getBlockTypeHandle()=="autonav"){
            $block->setCustomTemplate('cdrop.php'); // it's templates/cdrop.php -check the select option values when you set custom template manually at edit mode. I think you will need just "my_template" 
            $bv = new BlockView($block);
            $bv->render('view');
         }
      }
?>
```

There's the problem. No idea what so ever what that is doing there..... Removed it. Worked like a charm.

-Kevin